# sending mass email using java mail API

Tags: jakarta-mail

I have a requirement of sending emails to approximately 15,000 email addresses. Content of the email is same for all. I talked to my mail server administrator and according to him I can send only 500 emails/ hour. I wrote an utility using java mail API to achieve this. I am creating a connection(transport.connect()) and then reusing it.  My utility will be running for approx 30 hours to send all 15,000 emails. 
            The question I have "Is there any limit on number of emails being sent per connection? And is there any time out issues I could run into? Should I close the connection and get a new connection at some interval? like after sending 100 emails or after 1 hour?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers to all your questions depend on your mail server, not on JavaMail.  Talk to your mail server administrator again.

Comment: You are right. It is something that depends on your mail server settings. Mine is set to send 1000 emails per connection. And java mail API does not impose any such limit. Good to know stuff!